# Can extraction operator (>>) overwrite a variable?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I wrote the following test code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    stringstream ss;
    int num;

    ss << "54321";
    ss >> num;
    ss.str("");
    ss << "12345";
    ss >> num;

    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", num);
}
```

To my surprise, the result was 54321. How do you correctly overwrite a variable using the extraction operator (>>)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the first extraction, you reached the end of stream, so the `eofbit` got set and the second extraction failed.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    stringstream ss;
    int num;

    ss << "54321";
    ss >> num;

    // eofbit was set above,
    // we need to clear it
    ss.clear();

    ss.str("");
    ss << "12345";
    ss >> num;

    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", num);
}
```

Call [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) member function before you attempt the second extraction. <strike>The second problem is the position of the internal get pointer, which won't get reset automatically. Use [`seekg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) to set it.</strike>

EDIT: the striked stuff isn't neccesary, explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/str).

Answer (score 4):

When the stream reaches the end of the stream, `std::ios_base::eofbit` gets set. Before trying to extract any date, the extraction checks if any state flag is set and, if so, it doesn't do anything and your extraction fails:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "54321";
ss >> num; // sets eof:
std::cout << "eof: " << ss.eof() << "\n";
```

To have the stream do anything once any of the state flags gets set, you need to first clear the flags:

```
ss.clear();
ss << "12345";
if (ss >> num) {
    std::cout << "num=" << num << "\n";
}
else {
    std::cout << "failed to extract a value\n";
}
```

Personally, I generally don't use the output operators to set the string stream's content. Instead, I'm normally using the `str()` member:

```
std::ostringstream out; // note: this is just an output string stream
...
out.clear();            // the clear is still needed
out.str("12345");
```